# NullPointerException while working with Object array

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception

I am getting `NullPointerException` in this program. I believe there's some problem in declaring Object Array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class One 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        two[] obj = new two[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            obj[i].roll = key.nextInt();
            obj[i].name = key.nextLine();
            obj[i].grade = key.nextLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(obj[i].roll + " " + obj[i].name + " " + obj[i].grade);
        }
    }
}

class Two 
{
    int roll;
    String name, grade;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the objects in the array. Without this initialization, `obj[i]` contains a null reference.

```
two[] obj=new two[3];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    obj[i] = new two();
    obj[i].roll=key.nextInt();
    obj[i].name=key.nextLine();
    obj[i].grade=key.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your objects inside the array are not initialized.
Call `obj[i] = new Two();`
as your fist statement in the first for loop.
Btw: "two" must be uppercase "Two"